# React app created with VITE does not work in IE 11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, vite

I have a React app created with Vite which I'm trying to enable support in IE 11.

I have tried the `@vitejs/plugin-react` and added it in the vite.config.ejs file. It looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import legacy from "@vitejs/plugin-legacy";

export default defineConfig({
  envPrefix: 'APP_',
  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 500
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    legacy({
      // for ie11
      targets: ["ie >= 11"],
      additionalLegacyPolyfills: ["regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      polyfills: ["es.array.iterator"],
    }),
  ],
});
```

When I start the app and open it in IE 11, it simply does not load anything into the #root div. ALSO it does not display any errors in the console.

Alternatively I tried the `react-app-polyfill` and added the line `import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';` to the index.tsx file. In both cases the app simply does not load the content and it does not throw any errors. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You can take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6577), which says  "@vite/plugin-legacy only affects build mode, not dev mode".

Comment: @KendrickLi got it. Yeah, like they said, not clear in the documentation. 

Nevertheless, I tried the other approach of using react-app-polyfill. First I tested the approach with a blank create-react-app and it worked as expected. But then tried the same way in my VITE app and it didnt work at all and didnt display any errors... any idea of how it should work with VITE?

Comment: The same here. Not render and no error messages. I'm afraid that's by design in VITE and only applied to VITE. If there should be a workaround for VITE to work in IE 11, you could also create a thread there for further information.

Answer (score 0):

[tvkit](https://github.com/bfanger/tvkit) a proxy server that transforms a Vite dev server into something that can be processed by older browsers like IE11.

Start your dev server normally (running at port 5173) and then run:

```bash
npx tvkit@latest serve --browser "ie 11"
```

Visit the website from IE11 through the tvkit proxy at http://localhost:3000/